# ASP.NET MVC input validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently working on a blog application in ASP.NET MVC.

I can't quite figure out how to handle my input validation! As far as I understand the view itself cannot know about input validation!? So how am I going to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Scott Guthrie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Guthrie) has written something about ASP.NET MVC Preview 5, and form posting:

*[ASP.NET MVC Preview 5 and Form Posting Scenarios](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/09/02/asp-net-mvc-preview-5-and-form-posting-scenarios.aspx)*

It's a big post, but it walks you through a Form posting validation thingy. Remark that this is not the only way to do it, but it is a way.